# IndexError while handling multiple tabs in python using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, window, handle, index-error

```
 driver = self.driver
 driver.get("http://www.cdot.in")
 window_before = driver.window_handles[0]
 print window_before
 driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='http://www.cdot.in/home.htm']").click()
 window_after = driver.window_handles[1]
 driver.switch_to_window(window_after)
 print window_after
 driver.find_element_by_link_text("ATM").click()
 driver.switch_to_window(window_before)
```

but I am getting the following error:

Traceback:
    IndexError: list index out of range when executing window_after = browser.window_handles[1]

Comment: Yes it is a trace back, thanks for reminding let me edit it.

Comment: Is the `home.htm` link supposed to open in a new window?  If so, is your browser configured to ignore such requests and open the link in the same window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this solve the issue, #Handling mutliple tabs

```
browser=webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http:/google.com')
browser.execute_script("window.open()")
window_after = browser.window_handles[1]
browser.switch_to_window(window_after)
sleep(3)
browser.get('http://bing.com')
window_before = browser.window_handles[0]
browser.switch_to_window(window_before)
```